# c# using generic method

Tags: c#, generics, restsharp

I would like to know how I can solve the following problem:

I have a generic Method which return response data.

```
public class Request
{
    public T PostRequest<T>(string Ressource, T ObjTOPost) where T : new()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(Ressource, Method.POST);

        var client = new RestClient("https://api.net/api/v1/");

        request.XmlSerializer = new RestSharp.Serializers.XmlSerializer();
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;

        request.AddXmlBody(ObjTOPost, "http://api.net");
        var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

        return response.Data;
    }
}
```

When I call the Method like this it says that LoginXML cannot be converted to UserXML. I dont get why because LoginXML is a parameter only for serializing my properties for the post request.

```
var login = new LoginXML();
        login.username = tbUsername.Text;
        login.password = tbPassword.Text;

Request req = new Request();
UserXML user = req.PostRequest("sessions", login);
```

Here are my LoginXML and UserXML

```
 [SerializeAs(Name = "login")]
public class LoginXML
{
    private string user;
    private string pw;
    private string ID;

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "id")]
    public string sessionID { get; set; }
    [SerializeAs(Name = "username")]
    public string username
    {
        get
        {
            return this.user;
        }
        set
        {
            this.user = value.Trim();
        }
    }
    [SerializeAs(Name = "password")]
    public string password
    {
        get { return this.pw; }
        set { this.pw = value.Trim(); }
    }
}

public class UserXML
{
    private string ID;

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "id")]
    public string sessionID {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Is your client.Execute<T>(request) function causing the response.Data to return UserXML type? Mind sharing the client.Execute<T> function implementation?

Comment: I checked it and he returns LoginXML as type so thats why but does it happens automatically? There is nothing to share because client.Execute comes from the RestSharp: http://restsharp.org/ sorry have a mistake in my method call it should be UserXML user = req.Postrequest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public T PostRequest<T>(string Ressource, T ObjTOPost) where T : new()
```

Your `PostRequest` return type is `T`, which is similar to `T ObjTOPost`. Since you passed in a `LoginXML` instance into `req.PostRequest("sessions", login);` it'd assume your return type will also be `LoginXML` since they are both T.

```
public T PostRequest<T>(string Ressource, T ObjTOPost) where T : new()
{
    // Some code
    return response.Data;
}
```

Here you are trying to return the Data retrieved from your rest request which is a UserXML type. However in this case your method return type is `LoginXML` but you are returning a `UserXML` object instead, hence the error.

One way is to simply return object but it requires the trouble of casting every object and there will be potentially bad casts that causes exceptions.

Comment: Thanks! Is there no other way to solve it, like rename T or something, I dont really like the idea of returning an object type

Comment: I'm afraid my knowledge on generics are quite limited but maybe you can try out `T1`, `T2` like how `Tuple` does it. [Tuple Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm not really sure that would work. You might want to create a new question for that and see if anyone knows of any cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Maybe can do something like this.. 
public TRes PostRequest<TReq, TRes>(string Ressource, TReq ObjTOPost) where TReq : new()

Comment: This way, you can define both request and response types to your own likings.. where TReq is the requestType while TRes is the return/reponse type

Comment: this might be a good reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057636/how-can-i-write-this-class-to-be-fully-generic-and-return-different-responses-ac?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa